# What's the best way to migrate from mariadb to mysql on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I've got a server running on ubuntu 18.04.1 with mariadb 10.1. and I have to change to mysql. The reason is that mariadb isn't supported by a product I want to buy. Searching around the internet  I've just  found the opposite way.

Do I have to keep an eye on something special?

Current db-related software:

- ispconfig
- nextcloud

Any hint will be helpful.

Comment: @dbdemon I want to buy confluence. Confluence don't support MariaDB and there are some issues with it.
It's no problem to have a downtime on my server. But I'm not sure, if uninstalling  MariaDB, installing MySQL and importing the db dumps is the correct way to do it?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confluence officially supports [a number of different database systems](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/supported-platforms-207488198.html#SupportedPlatforms-Databases), including MySQL 5.6 and 5.7, but not 8.0, and also [does not officially support MariaDB](https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/is-mariadb-supported-by-confluence-829037434.html).

If you want to migrate an existing Confluence database running on MariaDB to MySQL, then `mysqldump` is a guaranteed route to success. Just dump the existing database to an SQL file, and then import this into MySQL using e.g. the `mysql` command-line client. This could be slow if it's a big database.

FWIW, the company I work for has a major Confluence installation on MariaDB 5.5, which is the default in RHEL7/CentOS7, and this has been running for several years with no known issues.